# Htaccess not working in pagination php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my link,
https://www.mangoloops.com/labels/zion-music
when i click 2nd page it is redirecting to 
https://www.mangoloops.com/productmanufact.php?id=zion-music&page=2 
this page ..
And when I enter direct in url(https://www.mangoloops.com/labels/zion-music/2) it is working.I want the url like these..
https://www.mangoloops.com/labels/zion-music/2

Can you guys help me why my htaccess page redirecting to 
https://www.mangoloops.com/productmanufact.php?id=zion-music&page=2 
instead of working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^labels/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/(.*)?$ productmanufact.php?id=$1&page=$2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.mangoloops\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]
RewriteRule   ^category/bundles$  bundle.php
RewriteRule   ^category/newarrivals$  newarrivals.php
RewriteRule ^labels/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ productmanufact.php?id=$1
RewriteRule   ^product/(.+)$  productlisting.php?id=$1&page=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
RewriteRule ^download_files https://www.mangoloops.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^website/(.+)$   page.php?id=$1
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php55” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php55 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: When you click on 2nd page on your website, what is `href` link? Can you not change that to `/labels/zion-music/2` ?